# Throws cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'validateStatus' error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

On click on a button I would to receive token in the client side, but I am getting below error in console
`TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'validateStatus' in sample1@test.com at merge`.
Could someone please advise what is casing the error.

`client side:`

```
const validateLink = () =>{
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const email = localStorage.getItem("userEmail");
                const res = await Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/validatelink', email);
                if (res.data) {
                    console.log("Link token created:" + res.data);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        fetchData(); 
    }
```

`server.js`

```
app.get('/service/validatelink', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userEmail = req.body.email;
    const data = await LinkTokenModel.findAll({ where: { email: userEmail } });
    
    if(currentDate < data.expiredAt ){
      let tokendata = data.token;
      res.status(200).send(tokendata);
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ success: true });
    }
     
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ fail: e.message });
  }
});
```

TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'validateStatus' in sample1@test.com
at merge (mergeConfig.js:67)
at Object.forEach (utils.js:247)
at mergeConfig (mergeConfig.js:64)
at Axios. [as get] (Axios.js:76)
at Function.wrap [as get] (bind.js:9)
at fetchData (createLink.js:37)
at validateLink (createLink.js:45)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `post` to send data to server. Also you should be sending an object with `email` property in order to access it like
`req.body.email` on the server.
Your code should probably be something like:

```
const email = localStorage.getItem("userEmail");
const res = await Axios.post('http://localhost:8000/service/validatelink', {email});
//--------------------------------------------- {email: "johndoe@gmail.com} --^
```

In this case server needs to be updated to `app.post('/service/validatelink'`

---

If the request has no side effect and you meant to use a `get`, it should be like:

```
axios.get('/http://localhost:8000/service/validatelink?email='+email)
```

Or

```
axios.get('/http://localhost:8000/service/validatelink',{
  params: {
    email
  }
})
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply I have changed to post , but now getting 404 error.

Comment: @soccerway did you change server to `app.post('/service/validatelink',`?

Comment: Yes I did 
`app.get('/service/validatelink', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userEmail = req.query.email;``

Comment: @soccerway I made a typo, for post it shoud be `app.post('/service/validatelink'` on the server. See the updated answer...

Comment: I have tried changing into ``post`` in server side, but no luck yet. I am getting error 500  Internal Server error.

Comment: That means the request is now working. Look at the server logs to see what is the error without your request handling code

Comment: I will figure today evening and reply back to you soon.

Comment: Now I am getting 404 error again...`
below is the client side 
  ``const validateLink = () =>{
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const email = localStorage.getItem("userEmail");
                const res = await Axios.post('http://localhost:8000/service/validatelink', { params: { email} });``

Comment: `app.post('/service/validatelink', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userEmail = req.params.email;
    const data = await LinkTokenModel.findAll({ attributes: ['token','expiredAt']}, { where: { email: userEmail }} );
    if(currentDate < data.expiredAt ){
      let tokendata = data.token;
      res.status(200).send(tokendata);
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ success: true });
    }
     
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ fail: e.message });
  }
});`